# Ubuntu 14.04, 13.10 and 13.04 have terribly slow graphic performance

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, 14.04

I think I've asked and googled this a lot of times. So many that I've lost the count. Anyway I have installed the three versions that I mentioned above and they all have the same issue and it is that the graphics are SUPER SLOW. Yet on Ubuntu 12.04 and even with Windows 8 the performance is smooth. I've learnt from what I've read so far that it is due to the graphics card or something because they appear not to pick up or to recognize my graphics card and they're using this: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
This netbook has a closed-source driver which is the cedarview-dm or something like (I don't remember very well) I have an Asus 1015cx with a Intel® Atom™ CPU N2600 @ 1.60GHz × 4 processor. I need help. How do I solve this? It's just that everything runs very slowly. Thanks

Comment: The only of the tree versions to recognize the closed-source driver that I mentioned above is the 12.04 version.

Comment: llvmpipe is very slow and any variation of gnome / unity will use it. I suggest you use kubuntu, xubuntu, or lubuntu, any version.

Comment: either that or upgrade your graphics card ;)

Comment: Go for xfce... That's the only way you are gonna get performance for Atom. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The Atom™ line of CPU's with the integrated Cedarview graphics are rather pathetic in terms of performance. I've used my Acer D270 netbook with 15.04 and it functions but I've never enjoyed the experience. (I'd rather use an I3 any day of the week). I would agree with @bodhi.zazen that moving to lubuntu or xubuntu would provide a far more acceptable experience. Since it's a netbook with integrated graphics upgrading the graphics card isn't an option in this case.

Sources: Experience,
[ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/58916/Intel-Atom-Processor-N2600-1M-Cache-1_6-GHz)